# Java проверка на null

Tags: java

Имеется класс City, в которой передаются параметры при создание экземпляра класса.

Некоторые экземпляры имеют значения null. Нужно вернуть строку, состоящие из свойств класса, через запятую, но чтобы при этом отсутствовали свойства, имеющие значение Null.

```
public class City {
    public int id;
    public String region;
    public String autonom;
    public String area;
    public String city;
    public String city_2;

    public City(int id, String region, String autonom, String area, String city, String city_2){
        this.id = id;
        this.region = region;
        this.autonom = autonom;
        this.area = area;
        this.city = city;
        this.city_2 = city_2;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        String title = "";
        if (region!=null) {
            arrayList.add(region);
        }
        if (autonom!=null) {
            arrayList.add(autonom);
        }
        if (area!=null) {
            arrayList.add(area);
        }
        if (city!=null) {
            arrayList.add(city);
        }
        if (city_2!=null) {
            arrayList.add(city_2);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            title += arrayList.get(i);

            if (i < arrayList.size() - 1) {
                title += ", ";
            }
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

Создаем экземпляр класса:

```
City city1 = new City(id, region, autonom, area, city, city_2);
 Log.e("Opa",city1.getTitle());
```

В итоге в Log проходят null:

```
E/Opa: Алтайский край, null, Ребрихинский район, Усть-Мосиха, null
       Амурская область, null, Свободненский район, Москвитино, null
       Архангельская область, null, Мезенский район, Мосеево, null
       Астраханская область, null, Камызякский район, Самосделка, null
       Брянская область, null, Почепский район, Московский, null
       Владимирская область, null, null, Владимир, Мостострой
       Волгоградская область, null, Октябрьский район, Громославка, null
       Волгоградская область, null, Серафимовичский район, Мостовский, null
       Волгоградская область, null, Чернышковский район, Тормосин, null
E/Opa: Вологодская область, null, Вытегорский район, Анненский Мост, null
       Вологодская область, null, Вытегорский район, Волоков Мост, null
       Вологодская область, null, Тотемский район, Мосеево Мосеевское Поселение, null
       Воронежская область, null, Аннинский район, Мосоловка, null
       Воронежская область, null, Каширский район, Мосальское, null
E/Opa: Воронежская область, null, Петропавловский район, Замостье, null
```

Что я делаю не так?
Пытался проверять так:

```
if(!city.equals(null)){

}
```

Но потом понял, что у null нету метода equals

**Upd** Данные приходят из БД c помощью JSON, который потом разбирается.

```
JSONObject paramCities = cities.getJSONObject(i);
int id = paramCities.getInt("id");
String region = paramCities.getString("region");
String autonom = paramCities.getString("autonom");
String area = paramCities.getString("area");
String city = paramCities.getString("city");
String city_2 = paramCities.getString("city_2");
```

Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте вставить в if    city != null

Comment: На метод класса getTitle посмотрите. Я именного и так проверял

Comment: может там строки `"null"`, в самом json

Comment: @zRrr да, оказалось что именно так. А разве MySQL не должен конвертировать Null значения правильно из Varchar

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Оказалось, что с MySQL данные null приходят в виде строки